# Modifying Grouped Bar Plot Colors with Missing Data

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization

I am creating two sets of grouped bar plots with similar data (one for 2017 and one for 2018). When I create these plots I see that one group does not appear in 2017 (Group 1), but appears in 2018. This is fine since there is no data for this group in 2017. However, I cannot figure out a way to force the legend to recognize this missing group. Also, I see that since this group is missing in 2017, the color scheme shifts. I would like the legends to be uniform regardless if a specific group exists in the data or not. So in this case, I would like the legend to display Groups 1, 2, and 3 even if those aren't in both datasets. Also, I noticed that when a group is missing, the bars get thicker to accommodate for the extra space. Is there a way to keep the bar widths uniform even if some groups are missing?

[image]
[image]

Here is the code to construct the datasets as well as create the plots I've made so far:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

#### 2017 Data ###
Year <- rep(2017, 21)
Month <- c("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Oct", "Dec", "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec")
Group <- c(rep(2,9), rep(3,12))
Count <- c(5,1,4,3,1,1,2,5,2,14,17,8,17,10,12,10,14,16,9,9,6)

dta <- as.data.frame(cbind(Year, Month, Group, Count))
dta$Year <- as.numeric(dta$Year)
dta$Month <- as.factor(dta$Month)
dta$Group <- as.factor(dta$Group)
dta$Count <- as.numeric(dta$Count)

tmp <- dta %>%
  mutate(Month = factor(Month, levels = c("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec")))

### 2017 Plot ###
ggplot(tmp, aes(x = Month, y = Count, fill = Group)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = .7, position = position_dodge()) +
  geom_text(aes(label = Count), position = position_dodge(.9), vjust = "bottom") +
  ggtitle("2017") +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(title =  "Group:")) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Pastel1") +
  ylim(0, max(tmp$Count) + 5)


### 2018 Data ###
Year <- rep(2020, 24)
Month <- c("May", "Aug", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec", "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec")
Group <- c(rep(1,2), rep(2, 10), rep(3, 12))
Count <- c(1,1,2,4,1,5,4,2,2,1,3,3,38,17,6,12,27,18,18,7,6,18,15,10)


dta <- as.data.frame(cbind(Year, Month, Group, Count))
dta$Year <- as.numeric(dta$Year)
dta$Month <- as.factor(dta$Month)
dta$Group <- as.factor(dta$Group)
dta$Count <- as.numeric(dta$Count)

tmp <- dta %>%
  mutate(Month = factor(Month, levels = c("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec")))

### 2018 Plot ###
ggplot(tmp, aes(x = Month, y = Count, fill = Group)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = .7, position = position_dodge()) +
  geom_text(aes(label = Count), position = position_dodge(.9), vjust = "bottom") +
  ggtitle("2018") +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(title =  "Group:")) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Pastel1") +
  ylim(0, max(tmp$Count) + 5)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your 2017 plot, you need to ensure that `Group` is a factor and contains all the factor levels. You also need to set `drop = FALSE` in `scale_fill_brewer`. To prevent the bars from getting wider when a group is missing from a data point, set `preserve = "single"` inside `position_dodge()`

```r
ggplot(tmp, aes(x = Month, y = Count, 
                fill = factor(Group, levels = 1:3))) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = .7, 
           position = position_dodge(preserve = "single")) +
  geom_text(aes(label = Count), 
            position = position_dodge(.9), vjust = "bottom") +
  ggtitle("2017") +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(title =  "Group:")) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Pastel1", drop = FALSE) +
  ylim(0, max(tmp$Count) + 5)
```

[image]

You can run the same code with your 2018 set (except changing the `ggtitle`), and you get:

[image]